# Showing tableView in Xib with data in Swift 3.0

Tags: uitableview, swift3, xib

I have taken a `Xib` of `UIView` named "CustomerView"  inside which i have dragged a `tableView` and also created a separate `Xib` file for `tableView`, How can show "CustomerView" view of xib.on View contoller and tableview with data in Swift 3.I know how to show customer cell with xib on view controller with tableview data.Can anyone help me i will be very thankful

Comment: Your language is bit confusing to me , 

you have a tableview inside customerView xib ,and u want to populate the tableview and present this whole view into view controller ?

Comment: yes you are right @saketkumar

Comment: @saketkumar pls up vote this question so i will get more answers

Comment: Dude , you have only one Xib right ? not two

what do u mean by and also created a separate Xib file for tableView,?

Comment: simply do something like = 

var t = customerView() // in customerView u do all stuff needed

view.addSubview(t)

Comment: i have a 2 xib in my project, In one xib i have taken a tableview and other xib is used to display cell @saketkumar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153607/discussion-between-anuj-and-saket-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here anyview is a uiview which u want to show or hide

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate {

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return any view
    }
    func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "Header", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 200;
    }
```

have a button action like below

```
    @IBAction func HideShowView(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if(!isSelected) {
        isSelected = true

        self.mytable.delegate = nil
        mytable.reloadData()
    }
    else {
          isSelected = false
        self.mytable.estimatedRowHeight = 40
        self.mytable.delegate = self
        mytable.reloadData()

    }







}
```

Comment: it is not working for dynamic tableview data @saket kumar